# Creating a layout which follows text box width

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to get the following layout which consists of three elements, an outer shell (div), a text box and a circle element:

[image]

But the problem I'm having is that I want the **outer shell div width to scale based on the width of the textbox**, meaning if the width of the textbox is smaller, then it would scale down as well.

[image]

Right now, i have the following in HTML:

[image]

Two issues is that, the circle i defined in CSS is not showing up which i wanted to get like the above, second is that the outer shell is not following the width of the textbox.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.outer_shell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.circle {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    background: blue;
}

#text_in {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "main">
        <div class = "outer_shell">
            <div class = "circle"></div>
            <input type = "text" id = "text_in">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation with the provided code and I found that the HTML appeared okay. The error was found in the CSS file. The following code snippet should work:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.outer_shell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 40px;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: fit-content;
}

.circle {
    width: 20px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 1px;
}

#text_in {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "main">
        <div class = "outer_shell">
            <div class = "circle"></div>
            <input type = "text" id = "text_in">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but the outer shell width is not resizing if the text box width is decreased

Comment: I applied the `width: fit-content` for the `outer_shell` as suggested by David and now everything appears to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, love your drawing.
You should use
`width: fit-content`
for your `outer_shell`